# Highcharts fixed / floating axis

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

I have the highcharts bubble chart inside an `overflow:auto` div with scrollbars.  This is because the graph is roughly 2000px per 5000px.  This means it's impractical to display on a webpage without scrollbars.

The problem I am having is that when the user scrolls off to the right and down, you cannot see the axis any more so the entire graph loses all sense without reading the tooltip.

Is there a way to allow the axis to float above the graph and move with it?

Edit: The following is an example using the standard Highcharts bubble chart.  The idea being that when the user uses the scroll bars, the axis should "float" with them and remain in the same position.  The content should be the only thing that moves.  That way the user can still see the X / Y axis even when they scroll.

http://jsfiddle.net/82ugmcnt/

Edit: The accepted answer allows for horizontal scrolling as I requested in the original question. The possibility for vertical scrolling does not exist yet in Highcharts/Highstock.

Comment: Could you replicate your issue as live demo ?

Comment: @SebastianBochan Thank you for the good suggestion.  I have added a jsfiddle.  Please see my original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use highstock.js which has built-in scrollbar.

```
    scrollbar:{enabled:true},
    xAxis: {
        max:50,
        opposite: true
    },
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/82ugmcnt/1/

Comment: Very interesting Sebastian!  I wasn't aware of that functionality as I thought highstock was for other features that didn't interest me.  I have one question though:  I require the scrollbar on the y-axis as well but placing a MAX value like you did on the X axis didn't work.  Is it possible to add the same vertical scrollbar?

Comment: Nope, the scrollbar for yAxis is not available yet.